# How to color a grid with image data?

Tags: graphics

I need to create images from some image data in the form of a (d x d) list of integer values representing the color of the corresponding pixel.

For small dimension images, I can use `Grid`:

```
d = 30;
g = RandomInteger[3, {d, d}]; (* Simulated data *)
dots = Table[Reap[Do[Do[If[g[[i, j]] == t, Sow[{i, j}]], {j, 1, d}], {i, 1, 
  d}]][[2, 1]], {t, 0, 3}];
color = {White, Gray, Green, Red};
Grid[Table[  , d, d], Background -> {None, None, Flatten[Table[Table[dots[[j, i]] -> color[[j]], {i, 1, Length[dots[[j]]]}], {j, 1, 4}]]}]
```

For larger dimensions (2000 x 2000), the Grid image is far too large to display, so I use `ListPlot` with Large/Medium/Small points, but that creates gaps or overlaps between the points:

```
ListPlot[dots, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Is there a way I can solidly color a fine grid?

My clunky conversion of `g` into `dots` in the 3rd line is only necessary for putting the data into a form `Grid` or `ListPlot` can handle.  My data will be in a form like `g` so if we can skip the `Reap/Sow` step that'd be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
gg = RandomInteger[3, {d, d}];

ArrayPlot[gg, ColorRules -> Thread[Range[0, 3] -> color]]
(* or *) ArrayPlot[gg /. Thread[Range[0, 3] -> color]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Create a matrix with the color in each cell:

```
im = Map[Piecewise[{{White, # == 0}, {Gray, # == 1}, {Green, # == 
       2}, {Red, # == 3}}] &, g, {2}];
```

Show the matrix as an image:

```
Image[im]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = RandomInteger[3, {d, d}];

Graphics[Raster[data, ColorFunction -> (color[[# + 1]] &)]]
```

And of course if you want an image you can `Rasterize` the `Graphics`